# How to Remove and create a input field with its parent Elements if Select tag change its value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a table with with four fileds as shown in figure

```
Semester | Exam Status | GPA | Fee Status
```

My question is that: When I change the value in `Exam_Status` the `Select tag->` is not cleared then `G.P.A` field can be removed on this, and when I select `Cleared` it can show me `G.P.A` field.

[image: working table picture]

HTML code which generate folloing piture output is following

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"> 
    <thead> 
       <tr>
           <th>Semester</th>
           <th>Cleared/Not Cleaerd</th>
           <th>G.P.A</th>
           <th>Fee Status</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>  
       <script type="text/javascript"></script>
       <tr>
           <td>1<sup>st</sup> Semester</td>
           <td>
               <select name="fexam_status" id="waqas">
                   <option selected="selected">Select Here</option>
                   <option value="Cleared">Cleared</option>
                   <option value="Not Cleared">Not Cleared</option>
               </select>
           </td>
           <td>
               <div class="gpa" id="work">
                  <div class="right">
                     <input class="spin-dec" type="text" name="fgpa" value="3.00" min="1.00" max="4.00" />
                  </div>
               </div>
           </td>
           <td>
        <select name="ffee_status">
                                <option value="Cleared">Cleared</option>
                                <option value="Not Cleared">Not Cleared</option>
                                </select>
                                <a class="deleteRow" style="margin-left: 10px;"><img src="gfx/deletered.png" /></a>
                                </td>


                            </tr>

                            <tr>

                                <td>2<sup>nd</sup> Semester</td>

                                <td>
                                <select name="sexam_status">
                                <option selected="selected" value="Cleared">Cleared</option>
                                <option value="Not Cleared">Not Cleared</option>
                                </select>
                                </td>

                                <td>
                                <div class="gpa">
                                <div class="right">
                                <input class="spin-dec" type="text" name="sgpa" value="3.00" min="1.00" max="4.00" />
                                </div>
                                </div>
                                </td>

                                <td>
                                <select name="sfee_status">
                                <option selected="selected" value="Cleared">Cleared</option>
                                <option value="Not Cleared">Not Cleared</option>
                                </select>
                                <a class="deleteRow" style="margin-left: 10px;"><img src="gfx/deletered.png" /></a>
                                </td>

                            </tr>

                            <tr>

                                <td>3<sup>rd</sup> Semester</td>

                                <td>
                                <select name="texam_status">
                                <option selected="selected" value="Cleared">Cleared</option>
                                <option value="Not Cleared">Not Cleared</option>
                                </select>
                                </td>

                                <td>
                                <div class="gpa">
                                <div class="right">
                                <input class="spin-dec" type="text" name="tgpa" value="3.00" min="1.00" max="4.00" />
                                </div>
                                </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

and similarly when i select **Fee_Status**-> not cleared it can show me a input tag insteat of SELECT TAG in FEE STATUS

Comment: Use the select boxe's `onchange` event for example: `<select  name="fexam_status" onchange="showHideGPA( this )">...</select>` as you can see i pass the current select tag object reference to the function `showHideGPA()` so that the function will be able to determine which select box was changed and traverse the dom to change the appropriate table cell.  Also of course you could use the select box reference to check its value and act accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/y45ZF/2/

It currently only works for the Cleared/Not Cleared drop downs, not for the Fee drop downs, but you get the point. The only change to your HTML code was that I added the "examStatus" class to the select elements to be able to treat them all in a unified way.